# Gaps and islands on 2 columns - if column A consecutive and column B identical

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, gaps-and-islands

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cc` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `number` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `datetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

The DBMS is MariaDB 10.1.26 on Debian 9.1. I had been trying to get it to list ranges of consecutive numbers. With the following query, I am able to accomplish that:

```
SELECT min(number) first_number, max(number) last_number, count(*) AS no_records FROM (
    SELECT c.*, @rn := @rn + 1 rn
    from (SELECT number FROM table WHERE cc = 1 GROUP BY number ORDER BY number) AS c
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) r
) c
GROUP BY number - rn ORDER BY number ASC
```

But if I wanted items bunched together based on the value in an additional column, this doesn't work. Say I want the items grouped only when their values for `name` are all the same. Say this is my data:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `cc`, `number`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 1, 12, 'Hello'),
(2, 1, 2, 'Apple'),
(3, 1, 3, 'Bean'),
(4, 1, 10, 'Hello'),
(5, 1, 11, 'Hello'),
(6, 1, 1, 'Apple'),
(7, 1, 14, 'Deer'),
(8, 1, 14, 'Door'),
(9, 1, 15, 'Hello'),
(10, 1, 17, 'Hello'),
```

I'd like to get a report like this:

```
first  last   count  name
1      2      2      Apple
3      3      1      Bean
10     12     3      Hello
14     14     1      Deer
14     14     1      Door
15     15     1      Hello
17     17     1      Hello
```

In other words, in addition to grouping items that are consecutive, these groups are split up into separate groups when their values of `name` differ. (In other words, items are only in an island together if they are all consecutive AND have the same exact `name`). The closest (and it's not very close) that I have come, is doing this:

```
SELECT min(number) first_number, max(number) last_number, count(*) AS no_records FROM (
    SELECT c.*, @rn := @rn + 1 rn
    from (SELECT number FROM table WHERE cc = 1 GROUP BY number, name ORDER BY number) AS c
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) r
) c
GROUP BY number - rn, name ORDER BY number ASC
```

This doesn't work, though, and what happens is it seems to return the first appearance of a name as `first` and the last appearance as `last`, with `no_records` being the difference in number between them, which is certainly not right at all.

I feel like [this question might be related](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114748/identify-multiple-gaps-and-islands-for-n-columns), but I've not been able to make much sense of it, and when I tried tweaking it to my table, it just did the equivalent of a simple `SELECT *` more or less. What modifications to my query do I need to make to get it to work?

Keep in mind:

- items can be inserted in any order
- Numbers can be repeated
- Names can be repeated, not necessarily consecutively

Comment: @GordonLinoff I might have mistyped something, but Apple is for 1 and 2 and Hello is for 10 through 12. How are they "combined"? Note that it is based on `number`, not `id`. I purposely mixed up the ordering of some of the INSERTs.

Comment: . . I misinterpreted the data.  It is rather confusing because the original data is not ordered the same way as the result set.  I think I get it now.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, I did that on purpose because I don't know if some query features like row variables go through in `id` ASC order, so I did that just to make it clear it should work regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much to change in your query. You basically need to select `name` and `number` in the subquery and sort in the same order. Then you can group by `name, number - rn` in the outer query.

```
SELECT
    min(number) first_number,
    max(number) last_number,
    count(*) AS no_records,
    name
FROM (
    SELECT c.*, @rn := @rn + 1 rn
    from (
        SELECT name, number
        FROM `table`
        WHERE cc = 1
        ORDER BY name, number
        LIMIT 99999999999999999
    ) AS c
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) r
) c
GROUP BY name, number - rn 
ORDER BY first_number ASC, name ASC;
```

Result:

```
first_number  last_number  no_records  name
           1            2           2  Apple
           3            3           1  Bean
          10           12           3  Hello
          14           14           1  Deer
          14           14           1  Door
          15           15           1  Hello
          17           17           1  Hello
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=3089f0e12753f06fcd1a603645060b32)

I usually advocate against the use of session variables in this way. The reason is that such solutions depend on internal implementation, and can be broken by version updates or settings changes. For example: Once MariaDB decided to ignore the ORDER BY clause in subqueries without LIMIT. This is why I included a huge LIMIT.

I also replaced `number` with `first_number` in the outer ORDER BY clause to avoid problems with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode.

A more stable way to generate row numbers is to use an AOTO_INCREMENT column in a temporary table:

```
drop temporary table if exists tmp_tbl;

create temporary table tmp_tbl (
  rn int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(64) not null,
  number int not null
);

insert into tmp_tbl (name, number)
  select name, number
  from `table`
  order by name, number;
```

The final SELECT query is identical with the outer query above:

```
SELECT
    min(number) first_number,
    max(number) last_number,
    count(*) AS no_records,
    name
FROM tmp_tbl
GROUP BY name, number - rn 
ORDER BY first_number ASC, name ASC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=df478643bbee14fb5e9f0f19113d15d8)

In a more recent version (starting from MariaDB 10.2) you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function instead:

```
SELECT
    min(number) first_number,
    max(number) last_number,
    count(*) AS no_records,
    name
FROM (
    SELECT
        name,
        number,
        row_number() OVER (ORDER BY name, number) as rn
    FROM `table`
    WHERE cc = 1
) c
GROUP BY name, number - rn 
ORDER BY first_number ASC, name ASC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=d5e6447aa216d953d289fe7a162fd58f)

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not a gaps-and-islands problem.  If it is representative of your actual problem, you can just use aggregation:

```
select min(number), max(number), count(*), name
from t
group by name;
```

I say this because gaps-and-islands is much more challenging without window functions.  And that begs the question of why you are not using a more recent version of MariaDB.  The end-of-life for 10.1 is October of this year, anyway.

EDIT:

As a gaps-and-islands, this is a little tricky because each name has to be handled separately.  The trick is to use `row_number()` with partitioning:

```
select name, min(number), max(number), count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by number) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by name, (number - seqnum);
```

If you have adjacent numbers for a name and subtract a sequential value, then the result is constant.  For instance:

```
Name   Number Seq  Diff
Hello    10    1    9
Hello    11    2    9
Hello    12    3    9
Hello    15    4   11
```

The `diff` identifies the groups for aggregation.

Oops, I forget this was for a soon-to-be-obsolete version of MariaDB:

```
select name, min(number), max(number), count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
               from `table` t2
               where t2.name = t.name and t2.number <= t.number
              ) as seqnum
      from `table` t
     ) t
group by name, (number - seqnum);
```

For performance, you want an index on `(name, number)`.  The performance should be reasonable, unless names have more than a few hundred rows.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=4f2a873486ebb03921b22772571b37c1) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I just ran this query. It fails just like the other things I've tried. Why do you say it's not a gaps and islands problem? Each "record" returned is supposed to be a range of `number`s which are consecutive and with the same name. If you take out the `name` part, it's a 1-column gaps and islands problem, no?

Comment: @InterLinked . . . In your example data, the only occurrences of `name`s are on adjacent rows with adjacent values.

Comment: Fair point - question updated to include that. Names could appear anywhere. In this view, I don't want names clumped together unless again they are in a consecutive range. I have a different view which is much simpler like what you proposed, where if I don't care about the numbers, then I simply GROUP BY the name and then COUNT(*). But in this case I want the numbers so it's a bit more complicated

Comment: This seems like this will work, but I'm still trying to get it too. The queries would not execute no matter what I tried and just said "Loading" forever. I am adding an index on number but that too says "Loading" until it times out. Isn't it not recommended to add indices on string based columns? (e.g. VARCHAR)? Right now, the table is only 400,000 records, and I'm wondering how this will work when it's 80 million records...

Comment: OK, I basically added indices to all the columns except datetime. Still, the query does not finish executing. I'm still trying to narrow it down to even a small subset of the data

Comment: @InterLinked . . . One index on two columns.

Comment: OK, I actually have a userid column as well that I left out in this example, should that be included as well? Or the cc column?

Comment: @InterLinked . . . You would need to ask another question with appropriate sample data and so on.

Comment: Well, I guess I should have included it earlier, but basically cc is almost always 1 and the userid can vary as well. What I've done for now is put indices on them all.

Comment: OK, I've added the (name, number) index as well, and the query still doesn't run, I terminated it after it just hung there doing nothing, which is what it's been doing so far. What exactly do you mean by "unless names have more than a few hundred rows"? I'm worried maybe that has something to do with it. Many of the names (not all) are unique. So maybe there are 100,000 unique names at the moment