# How can I get a rank query for contiguous dates and various column values

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

I got the following Input:

```
state        Date
success      01-01-2021
fail         03-01-2021
success      05-01-2021
success      06-01-2021
fail         07-01-2021
fail         09-01-2021
```

and I would like to get a rank query or maybe row_number query that does consider the state and contiguous dates, i.e:

```
state        Date         rank
success      01-01-2021   1
fail         03-01-2021   2
success      05-01-2021   3
success      06-01-2021   3
fail         07-01-2021   4
fail         09-01-2021   5
```

I would love to hear some ideas, since I have been struggling for the last hour to get something similar working. Same result with a different approach is obviously also welcome!

Comment: Why are rows 3 and 4 have the same rank, while rows 5 and 6 have different ranks? The states are the same and dates are different in both pairs.

Comment: because the dates are continuous and the state is the same!

Comment: You mean the dates are 1 day between? And I thing you mean contiguous rather than continuous.

Comment: oh sorry, gonna change that instantly! You are right

Comment: @P.Salmon I have just learnt a new English word, thank you :)

Comment: @F.V.: what is your mysql version? You probably want to check out the following SO question, since the problem statement is very similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62284967/gaps-and-islands-on-2-columns-if-column-a-consecutive-and-column-b-identical

Comment: Thanks @shadow for the link, going to check it out asap

Comment: Please use MySQL dates.  Those look like the first of consecutive months.  Anyway, you will need to store them in yyyy-mm-dd format for any SQL to work "correctly".

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you just use the LAG() function and compare State and Date you should be able to get the result you are looking for. But you will have to modify your dates as was noted above because they look like the first day of the month and not consecutive days.

Please Consider:

```
SELECT State,Date,  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Date,PrevDate) = -1 AND State = PrevState THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER(ORDER BY Date)
FROM
(
    SELECT *,LAG(Date,1,Date) OVER(ORDER BY Date) PrevDate,
             LAG(State,1,State) OVER(ORDER BY Date) PrevState from T
) T2
```